# retrieve child thread output in the mid of child thread execution

Tags: multithreading, perl

I am writing a perl script using [`threads`](https://metacpan.org/pod/threads) and [`threads::shared`](https://metacpan.org/pod/threads%3a%3ashared) modules where parent process can retrieve the result of child thread in the mid of child execution.

For eg. i need to get the output of child thread when flag=1 in the following script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use threads::shared;

my $flag : shared = 0;
my $num : shared = 0;

my $thr = new threads(\&sub1);

my @res = $thr->join();

print "@res" if ($flag != 0);

sub sub1
{

  for( $num=0;$num<1000;$num++)
  {
    print "$num\t";
  }

  print "\n";
  $flag = 1;
  sleep(5);

  for( $num=50;$num<100;$num++)`enter code here`
  {
    print "$num\t";
  }

  print "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to wait inside and outside the thread for the flag to be set/unset. See the comments in the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use threads::shared;

my $flag : shared = 0;
my $num : shared = 0;

my $thr = new threads(\&sub1);

# do some things here

#wait for thread to set the flag
while( $flag == 0) {}
print "Outside thread: num=$num\n";
#unset flag so thread can continue
$flag = 0;

# do some things here

#block until thread finishes
my @res = $thr->join();

print "Outside thread: num=$num\n";
print @res;

sub sub1
{
  #do initial calculations in thread
  for( $num=0;$num<1000;$num++)
  {
    print "$num\t";
  }

  print "\n";
  #set flag to parent can read value
  $flag = 1;
  #wait for parent to unset the flag
  while($flag==1) {}

  #continue with rest of thread
  for( $num=50;$num<100;$num++)
  {
    print "$num\t";
  }

  print "\n";
  return "I'm done\n";
}
```